# Searching with a wildcard

Tags: vba, excel, search, wildcard

In the following code, `shLook` is a sheet with a list of text items that I wish to search for strings in the sheet `shSource` by iterating through its rows denoted by `rowSt`.

```
LPosition = InStr(1, shSource.Cells(rowSt, 18), shLook.Cells(i, 1).Value)
```

This works well, however if any text in `shLook` contains a wildcard, it no longer is able to find corresponding string in `shSource`.

Is there another method to implement this so that I can put wildcards in the list of text items?

Comment: When you pass `shLook.Cells(row,col).Value` to VBA it consider it a string.  Wildcards should be used within the script itself.

Comment: I'm guessing this is in excel? Please add missing tags

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to know whether the string exists, you could use:

```
Dim found As Boolean
Dim searchString As String
searchString = shLook.Cells(i, 1).Value
If Left(searchString, 1) <> "?" Then searchString = "*" & searchString
If Right(searchString, 1) <> "?" Then searchString = searchString & "*"
found = shSource.Cells(rowSt, 18).Value Like searchString
```

If you then want to know the position where the string starts, you will need to strip the wildcard characters out before doing the `Instr`:

```
If Found Then
    LPosition = InStr(shSource.Cells(rowSt, 18), Replace(Replace(searchString, "?", ""), "*", ""))
End If
```

Note:  You can't simply do the second part without having done the first part, because you would get a false match in the case of searching for "?ABC" within "XYZABCIJK".

Comment: Wow, this is very helpful thank you!

How can I adapt the above code suggested by @YowE3K if the wildcard is in the middle of the search string eg. if I have a long list of Vehicle numbers, I would want the search String to be :

Vehicle_no_*_to_sell

as opposed to having to elaborate the search String for each Vehicle number :

Vehicle_no_1_to_sell Vehicle_no_2_to_sell Vehicle_no_3_to_sell etc

Comment: Are you really after the position where the match commences, or are you just trying to find whether the strings "match"?  `"Vehicle_no_1_to_sell" Like "Vehicle_no_*_to_sell"` should return `True`, so the first part of the code would work.  Finding the position would be more difficult.